# Does Alpine Linux Docker Image contain OpenSSL

Tags: docker, openssl, alpine, docker-registry

Does the [official alpine docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/) bundle OpenSSL.

I created a new container locally and I can't find the `openssl` command.

Is there an official doco with everything that's installed by default? I couldn't find it on the alpine website?

Answer (score 3):

Just install it.

```
apk add openssl
```

`apk` can also show you all installed packages.

```
apk list -I
```

Answer (score 1):

tldr: no

There's no documentation as far as i'm aware, but there's a build script. For container images, the following packages are included by default: https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/blob/master/scripts/mkimg.minirootfs.sh#L24

One can also inspect container images for what's included by exploring layer contents. I find [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) to be a neat tool for that purpose.